# selected value of dropdownlist from datareader

Tags: .net, vb.net, webforms

I have `dropdownlist` and I need to select the right state based on `DataAdapter`, but It does not select the correct state, just defaults at the first item.

Does anyone know what i am missing?

```
Dim Adapter As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT State From Customer Where userID = @UserID", "Data Source=myDataSource")
    Dim Dataset As New DataSet
    Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = UserID
    Adapter.Fill(Dataset, "Customer")
    Dim Val As String = Dataset.Tables(0).Rows(0)("State").ToString()
    State.SelectedValue = Val

<asp:DropDownList ID="State" runat="server" TabIndex="12" >
                            <asp:ListItem Value="0">--</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="AL">AL</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="AK">AK</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="AZ">AZ</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="AR">AR</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="CA">CA</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="CO">CO</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="CT">CT</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="DC">DC</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="DE">DE</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="FL">FL</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="GA">GA</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="HI">HI</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="ID">ID</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="IL">IL</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="IN">IN</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="IA">IA</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="KS">KS</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="KY">KY</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="LA">LA</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="ME">ME</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="MD">MD</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="MA">MA</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="MI">MI</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="MN">MN</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="MS">MS</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="MO">MO</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="MT">MT</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="NE">NE</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="NV">NV</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="NH">NH</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="NJ">NJ</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="NM">NM</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="NY">NY</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="NC">NC</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="ND">ND</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="OH">OH</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="OK">OK</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="OR">OR</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="PA">PA</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="RI">RI</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="SC">SC</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="SD">SD</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="TN">TN</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="TX">TX</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="UT">UT</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="VT">VT</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="VA">VA</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="WA">WA</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="WV">WV</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="WI">WI</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="WY">WY</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the values being returned from the database match up with the values listed in the drop down.

Comment: the database was set at char(10) for STate, which should have been char(2), that is why, it did not match up because of the extra spaces after the state

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
State.Items.FindByValue(Val).Selected = True
```

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. is the error i get on that line...

Comment: the value of Val is CA